# Failed upload file with UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH error

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am trying to upload an image using nuxt, uppy and my backend (adonisjs), but I've encountered an issue and I don't understand what I am doing wrong and how I could fix this issue.
here is how I am trying to do it.

in my nuxt application I have a file in my server folder where I am just redirecting the request to my backend

```js
// server/api/images.post.ts

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readRawBody(event)
  const content = getHeader(event, 'content-type') as string
  const length = getHeader(event, 'content-length') as string

  const {
    context: { params }
  } = event

  return await $fetch<{
    message: string
  }>(`/categories/${params?.id}/images`, {
    baseURL,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': content,
      'content-length': length
    },
    body,
    onRequestError(context) {
      console.log('==== onRequestError', context.error)
    }
  })
})
```

the error I am getting from this request is `UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`

`content-type` header looks like this

```
content-type':  'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------60647965127734541503372833747'
```

`content-length` header looks like this

```
'content-length': '893753'
```

Does anyone has an idea how can I debug further this issue? I tried everything I knew so far, but I don't know what to do anymore.